# Exit from ssl session

Tags: java, session, servlets, ssl, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to close a SSL connection, in case someone wants to use another certificate a webpage that uses client-cert as authentication method.
I know how to close a session, tanks. what i dont't know, how to invalidate a SSLSession.
apparently there is one, i can get it's id with request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.ssl_session")
and also apparently it is not enough to do session.invalidate(), why? because i have it in a logout.jsp
that redirects to my index.jsp. now if the SSL Connection would have been invalidated, i should be
asked to choose a certificate from my browser certs, which i'm not, after passing my logout.jsp
i'm still logged in, i even have a request.setHeader("connection", "close") in my logout jsp, which
doesn't help either (i have read that the header thing might be interpreted more as guideline for the browser
and not necessarily close all connections).
in tomcat7 there's the possibility to use SSLSessionManager to invalidate SSLSession, so i'm doing a guess, that something similar has to be possible with tomcat6 as well.

so the overall workflow would be

1. first hit of index.jsp
2. i'm asked to choose a browser cert
3. i log in with a browser cert
4. i hit the logout button, which makes an ajax request to logout.jsp
5. in logout.jsp i invalidate the normal HTTPSession and set the connection header to "close"

=> here some is missing to invalidate the SSLSession

6. in case of success of the logout-ajax request, i'm taken to index.jsp
   (now start over from point 1. again)
   only i'm not asked for a cert the second time, which is exactly what i want to achieve... and before you asked : i don't want to switch to tomcat7 for this
   but need it get done in tomcat-6.0.32

any help really appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You have to get hold of the `SSLContext` that Tomcat used to create the `SSLServerSocket`. From there you can go

```
byte[] sessionID = (byte[])request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.ssl_session"); 
SSLSession session = sslContext.getServerSessionContext().getSession(sessionID);
session.invalidate();
```

but I don't think this is feasible: at least I don't know how you get the `SSLContext` from Tomcat.